# How to pass a boolean to a switch parameter in Azure Cli (as in powershell)?

Tags: azure-cli

When calling a commandlet with a switch parameter, sometimes it's helpful to pass a boolean so that you can parameterise whether the switch is being called or not, using the `-SwitchName:$var` syntax.

For example, in powershell I can:

```
Get-AzureRmKeyVault -VaultName $vaultName -ResourceGroupName $kvRg -Verbose:$true
or 
Get-AzureRmKeyVault -VaultName $vaultName -ResourceGroupName $kvRg -Verbose:$var
```

...instead of the typical syntax for using a switch:

```
Get-AzureRmKeyVault -VaultName $vaultName -ResourceGroupName $kvRg -Verbose
```

Passing a variable allows you to not replicate the whole commandlet/function call when you may want to conditionally call the switch (in this example, only use -Verbose switches when a global debug variable is set).

In Azure CLI, both the following fail (within a powershell script) - is there an alternative syntax?:

```
az keyvault show -n $vaultName -g $kvRg --verbose:true
az keyvault show -n $vaultName -g $kvRg --verbose:$true
```

Note that I am talking about switch parameters and not plain boolean parameters :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, Azure CLI was not designed to work that way ([info](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/blob/8adf97355a605d147afc26f6c1b6f6afb6651c2f/src/azure-cli-core/azure/cli/core/azlogging.py#L6-L24)).

But feel free to ask/propose your ideas here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues so our Team can look at it.